# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, merge, overwrite

I removed everything in bin/class folder and committed, then when I tried to pull from master branch, git gave me an error listing all the files in bin/class from master branch:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: 
    bin/aaa.apk
    bin/classes.dex
    bin/res/crunch/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
    bin/res/crunch/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
    bin/res/crunch/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
    ...
    ...
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I think it's because I removed all the bin files and "git pull origin master" command will crash with my commit?!
How should I handle this situation? I don't want to merge with bin files.. or if that's not possible, I can just merge and remove bin files again.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.
Is there a good reason for the `bin/` folder to be under version control? Can its content be created from the actual sources? Do you want to remove those sources only in your branch or from the remote as well?